# Pointer variable is not working in cout function

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

I have written a code in c++ to check the variable increment (Screenshot added). In line 13 when I use "++x" in printing function to print the value of x and y. The value I'm getting is not equal but the memory address is same.
In line 17 I've incremented y as ++y and I got my expected equal ans 
(Screenshot added) [My Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwCBW.png).

What is the reason for not getting the unexpected ans in line 13?

My Code: https://gist.github.com/mefahimrahman/7fb0f45ae1f45caeb97d5aaeb39c4833

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 7, &y = x; 
    cout << "Whithout Increment: ";
    cout << &x << " " << &y << endl;
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    --x;

    cout << "After x Increment: ";
    cout << &x << " " << &y << endl;
    cout << ++x << " " << y << endl;

    y++; cout << "After y Increment: ";
    cout << &x << " " << &y << endl; 
    cout << x << " " << ++y << endl;
}
```

Comment: Post code __as text__, not as image.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=7,&y=x;
   cout<<"Whithout Increment:  ";
    cout<<&x<<" "<<&y<<endl;
    cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
    --x;
    cout<<"After x Increment:  ";
        cout<<&x<<" "<<&y<<endl;
    cout<<++x<<" "<<y<<endl;
    y++;
        cout<<"After y Increment:  ";
        cout<<&x<<" "<<&y<<endl;
    cout<<x<<" "<<++y<<endl;

}`

Comment: Add it to the question please, it's unreadable in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that in

```
cout << ++x << " " << y << endl;
```

`++x` will be evaluated before the value of `y` is accessed. In other words you are assuming that your output expression is evaluated left to right. But this is not necessarily the case. Change your code to this

```
++x;
cout << x << " " << y << endl;
```

and you will get the output you expect.

Also newbies sometimes assume that `++x` means the `x` will be incremented before anything else. But again this is not true, `++x` just means that `x` will be incremented before the value of `x` is taken, not before anything else.

Comment: Isn't the original code also undefined behavior? See draft n4659, 4.6/17 (was 1.9/15 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)): **If a side effect** [the ++] **on a memory location** [x] **is unsequenced** [which sub-expressions like the operands of "<<" are] **relative to [...] a
value computation** [taking y's value as operand of "<<"] **using the value of any object in the same memory location** [y refers to the memory locattion of x] [...] **the behavior is undefined.** Example in the standard: `i = i++ + i;`

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider You're probably right, but I think the exact diagnosis varies depends on the version of C++ so I given up trying to keep track. I think (don't quote me) that the OP's code becomes well defined with C++17.